# A DAG : Self referencing HASH: searching the first level parent from any level child and then search leaves of that parent

Tags: algorithm, perl, perl-data-structures

I have netlist (collection of subcircuits) of circuit schematic, generally is created by some SPICE simulator. It generally has hierarchy (A top level subcircuit calls or instantiates different subcircuits and defines some connectivities amongst them through pins). A sample netlist looks like:

```
subckt AN2D0 A1 A2 VDD VSS Z

    M_u2 (net5 A2 VDD VDD) pch 
    M_u1 (net5 A1 VDD VDD) pch 
    M_u3 (Z net5 VDD VDD) pch 
    M_u4 (net17 A2 VSS VSS) nch 
    M_u2 (Z net5 VSS VSS) nch 

ends AN2D0

subckt LS_RX_CONTROLLER VDD VSS burst_start_or_sys burst_start_out pd pd_pwm_det pd_pwm_det_TII std_by std_by_or_sys sys_en sys_out

    I2 (burst_start_or_sys std_by VDD VSS burst_start_out) AN2D2
    I1 (net22 std_by_bar VDD VSS sys_out) AN2D2
    I5 (net022 pd VDD VSS pd_pwm_det) OR2D2
    I10 (net026 pd VDD VSS std_by_or_sys) NR2D2
    I9 (sys_en std_by VDD VSS net026) NR2D0
    I6 (std_by VDD VSS std_by_bar) INVD0
    I3 (pd_pwm_det_TII net037 VDD VSS net022) OR2D0
    I11 (sys_en std_by VDD VSS net037) OR2D0
    I0 (burst_start_or_sys sys_en VDD VSS net22) AN2D0

ends LS_RX_CONTROLLER
```

Now in different hierarchies same subcircuit can be instantiated. Every called subcircuit is defined before the calling subcircuit. This kind of graph is called Directed Acyclic GRAPH. I have made a self referencing HASH table from a netlist to save the space. If a subcircuit is calling some subcircuit instance it is then pointing the pin. At the very last hierarchy we will get a MOSFET D or S or G or B node (as the AN2D0 subcircuit has been defined). If any net (connection between to instances' pin) is brought out form the hierarchy (nothing but calling subcircuit, e.g. net5) to parent calling subcircuit it is called pin(e.g. Z) and will always be listed in the present subcircuit definition line followed by its name (**subckt AN2D0 A1 A2 VDD VSS Z**). I have created a hash of hashes of hashes.

```
GRAPH --> subckt1--->p1
                     p2
                     net1
                     net2
          subckt2--->p1
                     p2
                     net1
                     net2
          subckt3--->p1 ---->I1.subckt1.p1--->pointing to value of p1 key of subckt1.
                             I2.subckt1.p2
                     p2
                     net1
                     net2
```

For the present case the GRAPH looks like:

```
the name of subcircuit-->AN2D0

     name of pin or net-->Z
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u2.nch.D
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u3.pch.D
     name of pin or net-->VDD
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u1.pch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u1.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u2.pch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u3.pch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u2.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u3.pch.B
     name of pin or net-->A1
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u3.nch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u1.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->VSS
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u2.nch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u4.nch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u2.nch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u3.nch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u4.nch.S
     name of pin or net-->net5
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u3.nch.D
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u3.pch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u1.pch.D
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u2.pch.D
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u2.nch.G
     name of pin or net-->A2
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u4.nch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u2.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->net17
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u3.nch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->M_u4.nch.D

the name of subcircuit-->LS_RX_CONTROLLER

     name of pin or net-->burst_start_or_sys
         name of instant connected to it-->I2.AN2D2.A1
            M_u3.nch.G
            M_u1.pch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->I0.AN2D0.A1
            M_u3.nch.G
            M_u1.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->burst_start_out
         name of instant connected to it-->I2.AN2D2.Z
            M_u2.nch.D
            M_u3.pch.D
     name of pin or net-->net037
         name of instant connected to it-->I11.OR2D0.Z
            M_u2.nch.D
            M_u3.pch.D
         name of instant connected to it-->I3.OR2D0.A2
            M_u3.nch.G
            M_u1.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->net026
         name of instant connected to it-->I10.NR2D2.A1
            M_u4.nch.G
            M_u2.pch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->I9.NR2D0.ZN
            M_u3.nch.D
            M_u2.pch.D
            M_u4.nch.D
     name of pin or net-->std_by
         name of instant connected to it-->I9.NR2D0.A2
            M_u3.nch.G
            M_u1.pch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->I6.INVD0.I
            M_u3.pch.G
            M_u2.nch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->I2.AN2D2.A2
            M_u4.nch.G
            M_u2.pch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->I11.OR2D0.A2
            M_u3.nch.G
            M_u1.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->sys_en
         name of instant connected to it-->I11.OR2D0.A1
            M_u4.nch.G
            M_u2.pch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->I0.AN2D0.A2
            M_u4.nch.G
            M_u2.pch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->I9.NR2D0.A1
            M_u4.nch.G
            M_u2.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->VDD
         name of instant connected to it-->I2.AN2D2.VDD
            M_u1.pch.S
            M_u1.pch.B
            M_u2.pch.S
            M_u3.pch.S
            M_u2.pch.B
            M_u3.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->I10.NR2D2.VDD
            M_u1.pch.S
            M_u1.pch.B
            M_u2.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->I0.AN2D0.VDD
            M_u1.pch.S
            M_u1.pch.B
            M_u2.pch.S
            M_u3.pch.S
            M_u2.pch.B
            M_u3.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->I6.INVD0.VDD
            M_u3.pch.S
            M_u3.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->I9.NR2D0.VDD
            M_u1.pch.S
            M_u1.pch.B
            M_u2.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->I1.AN2D2.VDD
            M_u1.pch.S
            M_u1.pch.B
            M_u2.pch.S
            M_u3.pch.S
            M_u2.pch.B
            M_u3.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->I11.OR2D0.VDD
            M_u1.pch.S
            M_u1.pch.B
            M_u3.pch.S
            M_u2.pch.B
            M_u3.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->I3.OR2D0.VDD
            M_u1.pch.S
            M_u1.pch.B
            M_u3.pch.S
            M_u2.pch.B
            M_u3.pch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->I5.OR2D2.VDD
            M_u1.pch.S
            M_u1.pch.B
            M_u3.pch.S
            M_u2.pch.B
            M_u3.pch.B
     name of pin or net-->sys_out
         name of instant connected to it-->I1.AN2D2.Z
            M_u2.nch.D
            M_u3.pch.D
     name of pin or net-->net022
         name of instant connected to it-->I3.OR2D0.Z
            M_u2.nch.D
            M_u3.pch.D
         name of instant connected to it-->I5.OR2D2.A1
            M_u4.nch.G
            M_u2.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->pd_pwm_det_TII
         name of instant connected to it-->I3.OR2D0.A1
            M_u4.nch.G
            M_u2.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->std_by_or_sys
         name of instant connected to it-->I10.NR2D2.ZN
            M_u3.nch.D
            M_u2.pch.D
            M_u4.nch.D
     name of pin or net-->net22
         name of instant connected to it-->I0.AN2D0.Z
            M_u2.nch.D
            M_u3.pch.D
         name of instant connected to it-->I1.AN2D2.A1
            M_u3.nch.G
            M_u1.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->pd
         name of instant connected to it-->I10.NR2D2.A2
            M_u3.nch.G
            M_u1.pch.G
         name of instant connected to it-->I5.OR2D2.A2
            M_u3.nch.G
            M_u1.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->std_by_bar
         name of instant connected to it-->I6.INVD0.ZN
            M_u2.nch.D
            M_u3.pch.D
         name of instant connected to it-->I1.AN2D2.A2
            M_u4.nch.G
            M_u2.pch.G
     name of pin or net-->VSS
         name of instant connected to it-->I11.OR2D0.VSS
            M_u3.nch.S
            M_u2.nch.S
            M_u4.nch.B
            M_u2.nch.B
            M_u3.nch.B
            M_u4.nch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->I5.OR2D2.VSS
            M_u3.nch.S
            M_u4.nch.B
            M_u2.nch.S
            M_u2.nch.B
            M_u3.nch.B
            M_u4.nch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->I3.OR2D0.VSS
            M_u3.nch.S
            M_u2.nch.S
            M_u4.nch.B
            M_u2.nch.B
            M_u3.nch.B
            M_u4.nch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->I6.INVD0.VSS
            M_u2.nch.S
            M_u2.nch.B
         name of instant connected to it-->I0.AN2D0.VSS
            M_u2.nch.S
            M_u4.nch.B
            M_u2.nch.B
            M_u3.nch.B
            M_u4.nch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->I2.AN2D2.VSS
            M_u2.nch.S
            M_u4.nch.B
            M_u2.nch.B
            M_u3.nch.B
            M_u4.nch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->I1.AN2D2.VSS
            M_u2.nch.S
            M_u4.nch.B
            M_u2.nch.B
            M_u3.nch.B
            M_u4.nch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->I9.NR2D0.VSS
            M_u3.nch.S
            M_u4.nch.B
            M_u3.nch.B
            M_u4.nch.S
         name of instant connected to it-->I10.NR2D2.VSS
            M_u3.nch.S
            M_u4.nch.B
            M_u3.nch.B
            M_u4.nch.S
     name of pin or net-->pd_pwm_det
         name of instant connected to it-->I5.OR2D2.Z
            M_u2.nch.D
            M_u3.pch.D
```

After this a subcircuit name and a pin of the same will be given which may be instantiated from any level hierarchy and we have to find the parent i.e. trace back the parent till the net has been pulled up as pin. And then stress back all the leaves(MOSFETS D or G or S or B pin).

Please suggest what kind of algorithm will be best suitable for this and whether the storing them in a Self referencing hash table is efficient or not.

Comment: What does "stress the parent" mean?

Comment: sorry for the typo. It is "trace back the parent".....

Comment: I'd look at the `Graph` module on CPAN. You can always do it yourself, but Perl's memory management can get a little fiddly when dealing with structures like these (it's easy to create a memory leak in any cyclic structures), and using `Graph` would make that Somebody Else's Problem. This provides an `all_predecessors` method you could use, then filter by the `is_source_vertex` method to filter the result; this may be the kind of thing you are looking for, but there are many other methods available.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I am trying with the same. What is memory leak, I have heard of but still not clear.

Comment: Perl free's an object's memory when nothing is referencing it any more.  Usually when the variable, array or hash falls out of scope.  The problem with graphs is that you can end up with a cycle where A -> B -> A.  In a program like this, a subroutine references A (in order to access it) and B references it as well.  When the graph falls out of scope the ref count drops by one, but it still has B referencing it.  But B has the same problem because A is pointing to it.  So A will never be let go, so neither will B, so neither will A, etc...  There are solutions... but out of space.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is better to use an indexing process to generate a unique identification of the nodes in your graph, then create a flat hash where the key is this id. Make the links using the id. For instance:

a => b, b => c, c => d, d => a

translates into

`%graph = (
    a => { content => ...,
           linksto => [ b ] },
    b => { content => ...,
           linksto => [ c ] },
    c => { content => ...,
           linksto => [ d ] },
    d => { content => ...,
           linksto => [ a ] }
  );`